# How to remove or disable onClick event listener after one click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making quiz app and I want to remove click after clicking on button. I tried many times to change code but without success. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { score: 0 }

    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }

  checkBtn(e) {
    if (e.target.value == "1") {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score+1});
      window.removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn, true);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn}>first</button>
        <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>

        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you trayed this.setState( {checkBtn : null});

Comment: react optimizes listeners and actually ads only one listener for a given event at the top element and then figures out what action to perform

Comment: if you set listener in react, you should also use react to remove it

Comment: @marzelin I tried to set it in componentDidMount and in componentWillUnmount and it have not worked

Comment: I searched for duplicates of this question and though there is some, they're old, rather not visited much and all answers were not good. So I chose to write my own instead of waiting for someone to do it since no one was coming up with the right way in React.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not use refs nor DOM manipulations. Just use React.**

Keep a `clicked` boolean state flag and just use a simple conditional when rendering the component.

```
onClick={!clicked ? this.onClick : null}
```

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  state = {
    score: 0, 
    clicked: false // simple boolean flag
  }
  
  onClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1,
      clicked: true // toggled on the first click
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { score, clicked } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Then, pass the handler only if NOT clicked */}
        <button onClick={!clicked ? this.onClick : null}>
          Only works once
        </button>
        <p>{score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: no, it is not right

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite what is not right? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The event listener cannot (or at least should not) be removed like this. Simply hold a variable in the state:

```
constructor() {
  // ...
  this.state = {
    score         : 0,
    disableButton : false,
  }
}

checkBtn(e) {
  if (e.target.value == "1") {
    this.setState({
      score         : this.state.score+1,
      disableButton : true,               // <-- disable
    });
}
}

render() {
  const { disableButton } = this.state;

  return (
    // ...
    <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn} disabled={disableButton>first</button>

    // or...
    <button value="1" onClick={!disableButton && this.checkBtn}>first</button>
  );
  }
}
```

You could also do the check if the button is disabled inside `checkBtn()`, but usually the recommended way is to use the `disable` HTML property if you also wish to visually show the button as disabled.

Comment: no, this is not sth I want. It just disables btns and when I want to add this button one more time it is disabled, so...

Comment: I meant to show the author where the change should go and forgot to add a `// remove this line` comment until I edited later on. I apologize, my bad.

Answer (score -1):

I hope it would help you.

```
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {score: 0}

    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }



  checkBtn = (mode, e) => {
    if (mode === 1) {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score + 1});
      document.getElementById("button1").removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button id="button1" onClick={(e) => this.checkBtn(1, e)}>first</button>
        <button onClick={(e) => this.checkBtn(2, e)}>second</button>

        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add listeners manually (which is not recommended) you should use `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods. Here's a working example.

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {score: 0}
    
    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.ref1.addEventListener("click", this.checkBtn);
    this.ref2.addEventListener("click", this.checkBtn);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
   this.ref1.removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn);
   this.ref2.removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn);
  }
  
 
  
  checkBtn(e) {
    if (e.target.value == "1") {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score+1});
      this.ref1.removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn);
    }
    
  
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" ref={r => this.ref1 = r}>first</button>
         <button value="2" ref={r =>this.ref2 = r}>second</button>
        
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```