# Remove click event in function

Tags: reactjs

I am making react quiz app and I have some troubles. I want to do like this: I have button that stores value 1 or 2 and it has onclick function that checks if the value of clicked button is 1, add one point to score. If it is clicked I need to remove click event from this button, only from this. 
I do not know how to do this. Help me please
Code:

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {score: 0}
    
    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }
  
 
  
  checkBtn(e) {
 
    if (e.target.value == "1") {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score+1});
window.removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn, true); // here i need remove listener
    }
  
  }
  
  render() {
    const { disableButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn}>first</button>
         <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>
        
          <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn}>first</button>
         <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>
        
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove or disable onClick event listener after one click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252122/how-to-remove-or-disable-onclick-event-listener-after-one-click)

Comment: Where do you add a click event listener to the window object?

Answer (score 1):

Turn this button into a functional element. Inside there, you can set a UI state (disabled: false, for example), then you render the element using the disable state to conditionally render your component, like this:

```
if(state.disabled){
return (your button JSX without the onClick event);
} else {
return (your button JSX with the onClick event);
}
```

You can use a onClickHandler to do the button job and set the state to remove the onClick event.

Comment: This is how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly good question, but I think to keep the approach as close to idiomatic React as possible, you need to think in terms of *passing props*, not adding or removing event listeners. In your case, something like this:

```
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      disableButton: false,
      score: 0
    };

    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }

  checkBtn(e) {
    if (e.target.value === "1") {
      this.setState(state => ({
        disableButton: true,
        score: state.score + 1
      }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { disableButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" onClick={!disableButton && this.checkBtn}>
          first
        </button>
        <button value="2" onClick={!disableButton && this.checkBtn}>
          second
        </button>

        <button value="1" onClick={!disableButton && this.checkBtn}>
          first
        </button>
        <button value="2" onClick={!disableButton && this.checkBtn}>
          second
        </button>

        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So you were close enough. Check out [the Codepen](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/LYYYzaY?editors=1010) to see how it works.

I'm not entirely sure if this really makes for a whole solution, but at least I hope if helps you move forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an event listener in React but you can tell it which function to run based on state. It sounds like if the score's 1 you don't want the user to be able to activate the function on the buttons with the one value, for that I'd change your render function to the below;

```
render() {
    const { disableButton } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" onClick={this.state.score === 1 ? () => {} : this.checkBtn}>first</button>
         <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>

          <button value="1" onClick={this.state.score === 1 ? () => {} : this.checkBtn}>first</button>
         <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>

        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

This way if the score is 1 it'll run an anonymous function that does nothing, otherwise it'll run checkBtn

Comment: @rapprogtrainsite it'll stop the button running the function, not disable it. What are you expecting to happen?