# Remove event from button

Tags: reactjs

I have a question. I am making quiz app and i do not know how to remove click event from button after clicking. So i have 4 buttons, 2 of them have value 1, so it will be right option. When i click on this button with value 1, it needs to add just 1 point to score, but my code adds one point after each click, and I need it so that if you clicked on the correct option, you can not click on this button, but on another buttons you can. And i need to do it this with each button that has value 1. I do not want to disable the button!

```js
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {score: 0}        
    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }
            
  checkBtn(e) {     
    if (e.target.value == "1") {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score+1});
      this.removeEventListener('click', this.checkBtn, true); // here i need remove listener
    }      
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn}>first</button>
        <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>            
        <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn}>first</button>
        <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>second</button>            
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Quiz />, Root);
```

Comment: What's wrong with disabling the button?

Comment: @Christopher Ngo at first it is not working and at second i said that i do not want to use disable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove click event in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58252678/remove-click-event-in-function)

Answer (score 0):

In "react way" you should use state/reference/global-variable indicator instead of query the click event.

Example with reference:

```
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  state = { score: 0 };
  isFirstButtonClicked = React.createRef(false);
  checkBtn = () => {
    if (!this.isFirstButtonClicked.current) {
      this.setState({ score: this.state.score + 1 });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          value="1"
          onClick={() => {
            this.checkBtn();
            this.isFirstButtonClicked.current = true;
          }}
        >
          first
        </button>
        <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          second
        </button>
        <button value="1" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          first
        </button>
        <button value="2" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          second
        </button>
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In your case, `this.removeEventListener` trying to reference the `removeEventListener` class function which is `undefined`.

[image: Edit Q-58255165-RemoveEvent]

Comment: but it works only on one button, but i need so it works on all buttons

Comment: No problem, just edit `checkBtn` logic, I'll fix it

Comment: Here you go, the main idea is clear just edit the logic accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a bit technical here but by definition, a button triggers an action so if a button cannot do that, it must be disabled.

"When the action associated with a button is unavailable, the button has aria-disabled set to true."

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#button

I get this is probably a project for fun, but if it's not, it's best to follow these conventions.

Also, here's a modified version on the answer above: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/q-58255165-removeevent-105eu

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      score: 0,
      first: "true",
      second: "true",
      third: "true",
      fourth: "true"
    };
    this.checkBtn = this.checkBtn.bind(this);
  }

  checkBtn(e) {
    if (e.target.id === "first") {
      if (e.target.value === "1" && this.state.first === "true") {
        this.setState({
          score: this.state.score + 1,
          first: false
        });
      }
    }
    if (e.target.id === "second") {
      if (e.target.value === "1" && this.state.second === "true") {
        this.setState({
          score: this.state.score + 1,
          second: false
        });
      }
    }
    if (e.target.id === "third") {
      if (e.target.value === "1" && this.state.third === "true") {
        this.setState({
          score: this.state.score + 1,
          third: false
        });
      }
    }
    if (e.target.id === "fourth") {
      if (e.target.value === "1" && this.state.fourth === "true") {
        this.setState({
          score: this.state.score + 1,
          fourth: false
        });
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button value="1" id="first" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          First
        </button>
        <button value="2" id="second" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          Second
        </button>
        <button value="1" id="third" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          First
        </button>
        <button value="2" id="fourth" onClick={this.checkBtn}>
          Second
        </button>
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here correct options may change. in this case option 1 & option 3 are correct.. in another case you may have option 2 & option 4 correct. So it is better idea to have Id or Class for option. the above code will work for all conditions

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.